# custom label x-axis in chart.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chart.js

[picture chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPzHc.png)

Hello everyone, i'm making chart by chart.js(follow above).
i want to move label on x-axis to bottom but still keep x-axis on top, i tried many way but i can't :((, please help me, thanks.
this my code js:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("chartComparementUserCancle").getContext('2d');
var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'horizontalBar',
      data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
        datasets: [{
          label: '# of Votes',
          data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
          backgroundColor: [
              'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
              'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
              'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
              'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
              'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
              'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
          ],
          borderColor: [
              'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
              'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
              'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
              'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
              'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
              'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
          ],
          borderWidth: 1
        }]
      },
      options: {
        legend: {
          display: false
        },
        scales: {
          yAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
              color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"
            }
          }],
          xAxes: [{
            position: "top"
          }]
        }
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("chartComparementUserCancle").getContext('2d');
var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'horizontalBar',
      data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
        datasets: [{
          label: '# of Votes',
          data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
          backgroundColor: [
              'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
              'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
              'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
              'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
              'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
              'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
          ],
          borderColor: [
              'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
              'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
              'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
              'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
              'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
              'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
          ],
          borderWidth: 1
        }]
      },
      options: {
        legend: {
          display: false
        },
        scales: {
          yAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
              color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"
            }
          }],
        }
      }
    });
```